# PIVOT - Agrupar Registros duplicados em uma unica linha

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, pivot

estou com um problema com uma consulta, na qual preciso transformar linhas em colunas. No caso pensei em usar a funcao **pivot**, mas nao deu muito certo, visto que o mysql nao me fornece tal funcao. Mas as tabelas são as seguintes:

[image: Tabela pedidos_lojas]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O Meu objetivo é exibir os resultados da seguinte forma
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No entanto a minha consulta ta meio atrapalhada, pois retorna os mesmos produtos em linhas diferentes e ae não consigo exibir dessa forma, mesmo tentando agrupar as colunas.

```
SELECT pq.id_produto,pd.descricao,
       CASE WHEN pl.id_loja = '1' THEN pq.produto_quantidade
       END LOJA1,
       CASE WHEN pl.id_loja = '2' THEN pq.produto_quantidade
       END LOJA2,
       CASE WHEN pl.id_loja = '3' THEN pq.produto_quantidade
       END LOJA3,
       CASE WHEN pl.id_loja = '4' THEN pq.produto_quantidade
       END LOJA4
FROM pedidos_produtos_quantidade pq
LEFT JOIN pedidos_lojas pl ON pl.id = pq.id_pedido_loja
LEFT JOIN lojas l ON pl.id_loja = l.id
LEFT JOIN produtos pd ON pq.id_produto = pd.id_produto
GROUP BY pd.descricao,
         pq.produto_quantidade
```

Esse sql gera esse resultado, que nao consigo agrupar da forma que mencionei:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguem saberia me auxiliar a fazer este agrupamento?

Comment: voce ja pensou em usar sub querys? voce perde performance mas no seu caso acho que atende bem..

Comment: Na verdade o mysql fornece a função pivot sim, você teria que criar uma procedure.

Comment: Você tem que usar `SUM(pq.produto_quantidade) as LOJA1` para fazer a soma corretamente.

Comment: algo como: `IF(pl.id_loja = 1, SUM(pq.produto_quantidade), 0) as QUANT_LOJA1`.

Comment: Outra coisa, é cuidado com `left join`, pois o `left join` traz tudo que é similar na segunda tabela... e no caso, você quer juntar alguns campos, então... para alguns casos, você deve utilizar o  `inner join`... [olha essa imagem](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VQ5XP.png).

Comment: @IvanFerrer mesmo com os IF e as somas os registros ficam repedtidos, o inner join eu inseri e nao alterou o resultado

Comment: @IgorMonteiro pode ser que a subquery ajude, mas ainda nao sei como fazer ela pra me dar um resultado proximo a ultima imagem que enviei

Comment: tenta fazer a consulta do colega abaixo jogando o resultado em uma tabela temp. Depois disso da um group by nas colunas que deseja agrupar colocando um sum..acho que funciona

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilizando a seguinte estrutura:

```
CREATE TABLE pedidos_lojas(`id` integer, `id_loja` integer);
CREATE TABLE pedidos_produtos_quantidade(`id` integer, `id_produto` integer, `produto_quantidade` integer, `id_pedido_loja` integer);
CREATE TABLE produtos(`id_produto` integer, `descricao` varchar(100));
CREATE TABLE lojas(`id` integer, `nome` varchar(100));

INSERT INTO pedidos_lojas(`id`, `id_loja`)
VALUES (1, 2),
       (11, 3),
       (12, 4);

INSERT INTO pedidos_produtos_quantidade(`id`, `id_produto`, `produto_quantidade`, `id_pedido_loja`)
VALUES (1, 1, 10, 1),
       (2, 2, 20, 1),
       (12, 1, 15, 11),
       (13, 38, 18, 1),
       (14, 44, 12 ,1),
       (15, 44, 22, 11),
       (16, 44, 10, 12),
       (17, 38, 9, 11),
       (18, 38, 29, 12),
       (19, 1, 15, 12),
       (20, 2, 18, 11);

INSERT INTO produtos(`id_produto`, `descricao`)
VALUES (1, 'Abacate'),
       (2, 'Abacaxi'),
       (38, 'Laranja'),
       (44, 'Manga');

INSERT INTO lojas(`id`, `nome`)
VALUES (1, 'Centro'),
       (2, 'Lagoa'),
       (3, 'Gloria'),
       (4, 'Serra');
```

Utilize a seguinte `query`:

```
SELECT pq.id_produto,
       pd.descricao,
       sum(CASE pl.id_loja WHEN 1 THEN pq.produto_quantidade ELSE 0 END) as loja1,
       sum(CASE pl.id_loja WHEN 2 THEN pq.produto_quantidade ELSE 0 END) as loja2,
       sum(CASE pl.id_loja WHEN 3 THEN pq.produto_quantidade ELSE 0 END) as loja3,
       sum(CASE pl.id_loja WHEN 4 THEN pq.produto_quantidade ELSE 0 END) as loja4
  FROM pedidos_produtos_quantidade pq
  LEFT JOIN pedidos_lojas pl ON pl.id = pq.id_pedido_loja
  LEFT JOIN lojas l ON pl.id_loja = l.id
  LEFT JOIN produtos pd ON pq.id_produto = pd.id_produto
 GROUP BY pq.id_produto,
          pd.descricao;
```

Resultando em:

```
| id_produto | descricao | loja1 | loja2 | loja3 | loja4 |
| ---------- | --------- | ----- | ----- | ----- | ----- |
| 1          | Abacate   | 0     | 10    | 15    | 15    |
| 2          | Abacaxi   | 0     | 20    | 18    | 0     |
| 38         | Laranja   | 0     | 18    | 9     | 29    |
| 44         | Manga     | 0     | 12    | 22    | 10    |
```

Na `query` descrita acima agrupamos os dados pelo `id` do produto e descrevemos uma coluna para cada loja, verificando o código da mesma em um `CASE` dentro do `SUM`.

---

Veja funcionando no [**DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gLWpVzfmQVAVMGstzhvMXs/0).

Comment: Amigo, obrigado pela ajuda, mas o seu resultado foi igual ao meu, os produtos ainda aparecem repetidos

Comment: Você pode postar a imagem de como ficou o resultado com essa select? Que dependendo de como ficaram os campos é só adicionar um "distinct" logo após a cláusula "select"

Comment: Ficou igual a ultima imagem que postei, mesmo utilizando o distinct

Comment: @tkmattos, corrigi o "group by" e testei com os dados informados. Agora ao que parece ficou correto.

Comment: Perfeito @Sorack excelente mesmo!!!

Comment: saberia me explicar pq utilizou a expressão sum(pq.produto_quantidade*(1-abs(sign(pl.id_loja-1)))) ???

Comment: Adicionada explicação conforme o artigo utilizado como base

Comment: @Tkmattos, é um cálculo que utiliza `sum()` - soma, `*` multiplicação,  `-` subtração, `abs()` - valor absoluto e `sign()` - inversão do sinal.

Comment: obrigado pelas explicações @IvanFerrer

Answer (score -3):

Tenta ultilizar o group by 'descricao' e sum nos dados que queira somar como sum(qtd_loja1) ou sum(qtd_loja2);

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).