# Consulta mysql linhas para colunas

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Olá, sei que já existe algumas perguntas parecidas aqui, mas nenhuma me ajudou.
Tenho a seguinte tabela no meu banco de dados:

```
+----------+---------------+--------+
| id_bolao | data_concurso | premio |
+----------+---------------+--------+
|   1      | 2019-05-18    |   1    |
|   1      | 2019-05-18    |   10   |
|   1      | 2019-05-18    |   22   |
|   1      | 2019-05-18    |   45   |
|   1      | 2019-05-18    |   70   |
|   1      | 2019-05-19    |   3    |
|   1      | 2019-05-19    |   4    |
|   1      | 2019-05-19    |   47   |
|   1      | 2019-05-19    |   34   |
|   1      | 2019-05-19    |   80   |
+----------+---------------+--------+
```

E eu preciso chegar no seguinte resultado, porém esses valores não são fixos. todos os dias serão cadastrados novos concursos com 5 premios diferentes:

```
+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|id_bolao| data_concurso | premio1 | premio2 | premio3 | premio4 | premio5 |
+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   1    | 2019-05-18    |   1     |    10   |    22   |    45   |   70    |
|   1    | 2019-05-19    |   3     |    4    |    47   |    34   |   80    |
+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

As perguntas já existentes na comunidade dão soluções com valores constantes e não valores dinâmicos.
Alguma ideia?

Comment: Antes de qualquer coisa, comece fazendo o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender como a comunidade funciona; depois leia o guia de [Como perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) para verificar como pode melhorar sua pergunta e, por fim, acesse a [central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help) para verificar vários artigos que te lhe ajudarão a entender melhor o site.

Comment: Já fiz a leitura do tour amigo, e acredito que a pergunta está bem clara! Obrigado

Comment: Possível duplicata de [PIVOT - Agrupar Registros duplicados em uma unica linha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/162534/pivot-agrupar-registros-duplicados-em-uma-unica-linha)

Comment: Relacionado: [PIVOT - SELECT invertendo linha e coluna](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/163386/pivot-select-invertendo-linha-e-coluna/163397#163397).

Comment: Qual a versão do `MySQL`?

Comment: O sistema funcionará da seguinte forma, todos os dias serão cadastrados novos concursos com 5 premios diferentes, mas ao mostrar a consulta na tela não gostaria de mostrar em várias linhas os premios do mesmo concurso, mas sim todos os prêmios na mesma linha, conforme o exemplo.

Comment: Versão do MySQL 5.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver meu problema acima adicionando mais um campo: `sequencia` na minha tabela, é um campo que será sempre de 1 a 5 nos concursos lançados todos os dias. A consulta ficou assim:

```
SELECT
   id_bolao,
   data_concurso,
   max(CASE sequencia WHEN 1 THEN premio ELSE 0 END) as premio1,
   max(CASE sequencia WHEN 2 THEN premio ELSE 0 END) as premio2,
   max(CASE sequencia WHEN 3 THEN premio ELSE 0 END) as premio3,
   max(CASE sequencia WHEN 4 THEN premio ELSE 0 END) as premio4,
   max(CASE sequencia WHEN 5 THEN premio ELSE 0 END) as premio5
FROM 
   bolao_concurso
GROUP BY 
   data_concurso;
```